# Can I have a state as a input signal at a state space model?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, control-theory, simulation

Assume that we have this ODE which describes a hydraulic cylinder.

$$M\ddot{x} = AP - B\dot{x} - F_L$$

Where $M$ is mass and and $A$ is the piston area and $P$ is the pressure and $B$ is the damping and $F_L$ is the force load on the mass.

One problem with this is that this ODE is for a hydraulic cylinder. We cannot choose a pressure $P$ because the load $F_L$ is determining the pressure $P$.

To make the cylinder move up/down, the pressure $P$ need to be larger that $F_L$. The pressure only need to be a little bit lager, not so much. The speed of the hydraulic cylinder is determined by the flow $Q$.

The formula for the flow is:

$$Q = Dn$$

Where $D$ is the deplacement of the pump and $n$ is the revolution of the pump shaft.

The flow $Q$ is also equal to

$$A\dot{x} = Q = Dn$$

Where $\dot{x}$ is the velocity of the piston and $A$ is the piston area.
So my idea is to rewrite the ODE like this:

$$M\ddot{x} = \frac{D}{A}n - B\dot{x} - F_L$$

Because

$$\dot{x} = \frac{D}{A}n$$

And now you may wonder "Is not $\dot{x}$ a state?. Yes it is, and that's why I asking you if this ODE is correct done?

I replace the $AP$ with $\frac{D}{A}n$ and let the revolution $n$ be the input signal. Because when $\dot{x} = F_L$, then the cylinder stop.

Comment: Are the units correct? Because pressure is N/m^2 and $D/A^2 n$ is [n]/m^3, then $n$ must be Nm. Is this the case? Furthermore, can you clarify why „\dot x=F“ is important for the choice of n as input?

Comment: No sorry. $n$ is Rad/s and D is cm^3/rad.

Comment: Then the answer is simple: yes you can use $n$ as input

Comment: @Carlos Thanks! So I can use this flow equation: $$M\dot{x} = \frac{D}{A}n - B\dot{x} - F_L$$ instead of the pressure input equation: $$M\dot{x} = AP - B\dot{x} - F_L$$ ?

Comment: Can you simulate both variants? I assume there is no problem using $n$ as input. The origin (for $D/A n - F_L = 0$) of the ODE is stable (since $B>0$) as also for $AP-F_L = 0$ (note: not asymptotically stable). That is, the position of the zylinder is theoretically increasing for all times when $D/A\,n - F_L \ne0$. And with $n$ as input you can control the system. Actually you could set $u = D/A\,n - F_L $ as new input.

Comment: @Carlos In a state space model, I can simulate both variants. But I don't know how to set up the equations. I'm sure that I need a force equation: $M\ddot{x} = AP - B\dot{x} - F_L$ and then a flow equation. But I don't know the flow equation.

Comment: Maybe you could use something like this: $\dot P = \frac{1}{V(x)}(q-A\,\dot x)$, where $V$ is the volume of the cylinder chamber. Then the volume flow $q$ would be the input.

Comment: When I should design a feedback controller, a first approach might be to choose $n = \frac{A}{D}\left( -(x-x_s) + F_L\right)$, where $x_s$ is the desired stationary position of the cylinder. Then, you can also check if the necessary values of the revolution profile are reasonable.

Comment: @Carlos Hi again! Now I found something: $$q = A\dot{x} + \frac{V}{\beta}\dot{p}$$ This is called the flow equation in hydraulics. The $V$ is the volume for each side. I know that the volume depending on time and bulk modulus $\beta$ so. But I need to assume that they are constants.

Comment: The volume depends on $x$, not on time explicitly. Its a nonlinear ODE. As far I know, its OK to assume $\beta$ being constant.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. What are your inputs? Is $P$ a function of $F_\text{L}$? If yes then you should write the ODE as $$M\ddot{x} = -B\dot{x} +(AP(F_\text{L})-F_\text{L}).$$ If you also have a linear relationship for $P(F_\text{L})=\alpha F_\text{L}$, then you can treat this problem as a standard linear control problem. You should also change your notation, in control theory capital letters are used for matrices and not for scalars (which I assume is the case for your problem).